# How can I add 'duration' column in the given DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am pretty new to Python and doing some project work on my own. Hence need a little help to understand a few things.

I have a **DataFrame** that contains **Netflix Data**.

[image]

what I need to do is to Find out the **Sum of DURATION column** for **each Profile Name** i.e want to know who watches Netflix the most.

How can I add the duration Column? I am unable to understand the **to_timedelta** function.

Comment: please provide the output of `df.head(5).to_dict('list')` (and ideally of `df.groupby('Profile Name').head(5).to_dict('list')`) as **text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
out = (pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'])       # convert strings to timedelta
         .groupby(df['Profile Name']).sum()  # sum per Profile
         .sort_values(ascending=False)       # sort by total duration
       )

print(out)
```

Comment: did you mean `df.assign(duration=pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']))`?

Comment: @SergFSM no, you can group a Series with another aligned Series ;) But you could also assign…

Comment: @mozway can you please help me with plotting the same? to make it more Visual.